# Coffeescript assoc array syntax in a list comprehension

Tags: associative-array, list-comprehension, coffeescript

Hi everyone: I'm often running into the following issue with coffeescript and was wondering if anyone knows of a solution. Consider the following code:

```
k=for x in [0...3]
   {foo:{bar:x,baz:3},qux:5}
```

I have a lot of code that has this basic layout. However, it is hard to read. It would be cleaner to write this code in the following manner:

```
#Gives Error- PARSE ERROR ON LINE 5: UNEXPECTED 'TERMINATOR'
k=for x in [0...3]
   foo:
      bar:x
      baz:3
   qux:5
```

This error can be circumvented with the following hack, which looks really ugly:

```
k=for x in [0...3]
   g=
      foo:
         bar:x
         baz:3
      qux:5
   g
```

Does anybody know a clean way to use Coffeescript's multi-line assoc array syntax inside of a comprehension without running into this error? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So,

```
k=for x in [0...3]
   foo:
      bar:x
      baz:3
   qux:5
```

fails to compile, but

```
func
   foo:
      bar:x
      baz:3
   qux:5
```

(for instance) compiles correctly. I believe this is a known bug in the CoffeeScript parser. Unfortunately, there are several similar issues open, as parsing YAML-style objects has turned out to be exceptionally tricky. So for now, I'd use explicit curly braces, as c3rin suggests.

[**Edit**: See [issue 981](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/981) specifically.]

Comment: yes, this is clearly exactly the crux of the issue- Thanks for the link to the bug report.

Answer (score 3):

`.map()` is your friend here:

```
k = [0...3].map (i) ->
    foo:
        bar: "#{i}"
        baz: i
    qux: i*3
```

(i know your problem is actually a bug, but this makes more sense IMO. list comprehensions are better suited to simple tasks)

Answer (score 2):

I've changed my answer a couple of times, but I think the issue with your first example is that coffeescript compiler thinks that foo:  is the object you want to build and is concerned when it gets to qux: because it thinks its a different object altogether than foo.  What's interesting is that you can mix the JSON-style and YAML-style declarations, using the JSON-style curly braces to explicitly declare the boundaries of the object definition, and the use YAML inside of the boundaries for readability.

```
{
  foo:
    bar:x
    baz:3
  qux:5
}
```

Comment: Thanks- This is what I'll do. (But I had to declare Trevor as the right answer, since he actually found the bug report for this. But I gave you a point :-)

Comment: thats fair!  I'm not even sure I could declare an object without the braces even when the bug gets fixed.  That syntax confuses me.  It just looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

My usual solution for this is the following:

```
k = for x in [0...3]
   g =
      foo:
         bar:x
         baz:3
      qux:5
```

Setting a variable returns the value it is set to.  Its still a bit hacky, but slightly nicer than your version that explicitly returns `g` after setting it.  Definitely a workaround for a coffeescript bug, though.